# How to import spacy 3 on a unix box having glibc 2.14?

Tags: python-3.x, unix, rhel, spacy-3

I have installed spacy 3.0.4 on my Unix machine having glibc 2.12. When I do `import spacy`, it throws me an error saying **version 'GLIBC_2.14'** not found. Is there any workaround to fix this other than upgrading to 2.14?

Comment: What's the full error? You can always install spaCy from source.

Comment: My error is gone when I used a machine which had a higher kernel version